# Create an Apex form with multiple pages

Tags: oracle, user-interface, oracle-apex

I'm trying to make an apex form that has multiple 'pages' within it, so that I can achieve a nice layout.

For example:
Page 1 - Personal Details >> Page 2 - Occupation >> Page 3 - Career History >> Submit

Is there a way to do this without submitting one page at a time as this would mess up my validation for the table entry.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you. You want create wizard? Apex has such type of pages, click `Create page`, choose type `Wizard`, after that you can set number of pages for wizard, and so on. Also, use tag `oracle-apex` for Application Express.

Comment: Another vote for the wizard idea. Note however, that each page in the wizard *will* do a page submit; but the idea is that only the last page would do the table insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of a broad question - lots of possible solutions. You will need to create several regions on the page, so that you can easily show or hide different sets of page items without submitting the page.

If you simply want to keep the page tidy, you could make use of the `Hide and Show Region` template, or you could create a `Region Display Selector` region.

To help the user experience flow a bit better, I would probably do something like this:

1. Set up the page items using the Form wizard.
2. Create three HTML regions - `Personal Details`, `Occupation`, and `Career History`.
3. Move the page items into the appropriate regions.
4. Delete the original region created by the wizard, together with the default buttons.
5. Create navigation buttons in each region - probably a `Next` button in `Personal Details`, `Next` and `Previous` buttons in `Occupation`, and `Previous` and `Submit` in `Career History`.
6. Create dynamic actions for each of the buttons. The `Submit` button submits the page of course. The `Next` and `Previous` buttons show and hide the regions as appropriate.