# Oracle Apex create a form that is split into multiple regions

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle-apex

I have a merchant application form that I want to split up into multiple regions so that the user only has to see one section of the application at a time. Each region is tied to the same table therefore:

1. Each region would have to share the same primary key
2. I only want one submission of the form items at the end of the form

I read this post [Create an Apex form with multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108518/create-an-apex-form-with-multiple-pages)
which makes it seem like an easy to do process by using the `Hide and Show Region` template and manually separate the form into multiple regions. The problem I'm running into is that Apex requires a primary key to be tied to each form region, but you also can not have duplicate items on the same page. Any ideas?

-- attaching the PNG of the error message here [Primary Key ERR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUdl0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks like a single page with several regions. Doing so, you'd have only one primary key item.

Logically, you'd separate items into different regions. Each of them should use its "Server side condition" which would decide whether to render (i.e. display) that region at certain time or not. It means that it doesn't have to be a *hide and show* region (besides, it is always here and visible, user just decides whether to reveal its contents or not). You'd create any region type (even an ordinary HTML region).

For example:

- the first region displays customer ID, name and address. Other regions are "hidden" because e.g. `P1_ID IS NULL` is met as no data has been submitted yet. Once user enters ID, name and address and submits the page, `P1_ID` gets its value which enables other region(s) to be displayed
- the second region contains items about some other customer's data; it is now visible because `P1_ID` is no longer `NULL`, but 3rd region is still hidden as you didn't enter some required data in the 2nd region which would let the 3rd region to be displayed.
- and so forth

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really like the idea of using the "server side condition" to display each region. I'm now using multiple regions with the type "Static Content" and then setting each item's source to its respective column in the "Form" region.

Comment: One last question, Is it possible to have two server side conditions applied to one region? That way the already completed regions can be hidden therefore only displaying one region at a time? I'm assuming that might require some PL/SQL

Comment: No, there's only one condition. But, you can use **function** (that returns Boolean)  (as a condition) and - as you said - write PL/SQL code which will *do the logic* you need.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the post you are referring to is 6 years old. That is like medieval in apex terms - so much has changed since then.

This is a way to do it if you want multiple pages. Just create multiple pages with the same form (using the create form functionality) and depending on the functionality needed on a specific page you delete the page items you don't want to show. If a database column is not included in the form it will not be touched by the dml process. This should be relatively simple to create.

Note: if you want to get up to speed on forms, read this [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/forms-in-apex-191-more-power%2C-more-flexibility)